# twitter gemのレスポンスからdisplay urlを取得する方法

Tags: ruby, rubygems

https://github.com/sferik/twitter を利用して画像つきツイートをした後に、画像のURLをレスポンスから取得する方法が分からず困っています。

```
 res = client.update_with_media("I'm tweeting with @gem!", media)
```

返り値がTwitter:Tweetオブジェクトであることは分かっているのですが、display_urlやmedia_urlをとるメソッドが分かりません。
ご存じであればご教示頂ければと思います

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res.media[0].media_url.to_s
```

だと画像添付が無い場合にエラーになってしまいます。また Twitter は画像が4枚まで添付出来ます。
ですので、

```
res.media.map{ |photo| photo.media_url.to_s }
```

でURLの配列を取得した方がよいと思います。画像添付が無い場合、エラーにならず空配列が返るだけですので安心です。

Answer (score 2):

これでいけました

```
res.media[0].media_url.to_s
```